# Can I use the latest C2x language features in developing a Python extension module?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I wonder if I can use the latest C2x features in developing a Python extension module, since the CPython itself is written partially in C89 and borrowing some features from C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you want in your own module. C as Python uses it works with both C89 compilers (MSVC) and compilers that support more modern standards (literally every other relevant C compiler today). Just don't expect your code to ever be merged into upstream Python if you violate [PEP 7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/) like that.